# How to solve matrix equation of type: MatrA*X +MatrB=MatrC, for X, where X is supposed to be matrix as well

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

Here is the example of an equation, I'm trying to solve:

The equation:
http://mathprofi.ru/i/matrichnye_uravneniya_primery_reshenij_clip_image012.gif

The solution:http://mathprofi.ru/i/matrichnye_uravneniya_primery_reshenij_clip_image023_0000.gif

I tried to use `Solve`, but apparently it doesn't work the way I expected:

```
In[132]:= matrixA:={{1,-3},{8,0}}
matrixB:=3 {{-1,1},{0,4}}

In[131]:= Solve[matrixA-2 X==matrixB,X]

Out[131]= {}
```

Comment: You need to specify the unknown `X = {{x1,x2},{x3,x4}}`, and type `Solve[matrixA-2 X==matrixB,{x1,x2,x3,x4}]`. Also, there is no need to use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) here; use `Set` (`=`).

Comment: it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it:

A = {{1, -3}, {8, 0}};
X = {{x11, x12}, {x21, x22}};
B = {{-1, 1}, {0, 4}};

Solve[A - 2*X == 3*B, Flatten[X]]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to easily convert the output into matrix, rather than manually extract `x1, x2, x3, x4` from the solution, using `Evaluate`?

Comment: Something like this?Flatten[X] /. Solve[A - 2*X == 3*B, Flatten[X]]

Comment: Not exactly. The result of `Flatten[X] /. Solve[A - 2*X == 3*B, Flatten[X]]` is `{{5,-6,4,-18}}`, but it supposed to be `{{5,-6},{4,-18}}`

Comment: Ok!  So it would be:   First[X /. Solve[A - 2*X == 3*B, Flatten[X]]]